# Cannot call external function using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Here's my jquery code

```
<script>
      $(function () {

        $('#deleteform').on('submit', function (e) {

          e.preventDefault();

          $.ajax({
            type: 'get',
            url: 'delete.php',
            success: function () {
              alert('Worked');
            }
          });

        });

      });
    </script>
```

And my PHP code (I'm just trying to test it out, so I added a simple function)

```
<?php
  header("Location: http://www.google.com/");
?>
```

And nothing happens when I click the button (when the form submit) except that "Worked" alert box. But whatever I put in that PHP file (delete.php), nothing happens. What am I doing wrong? My "delete.php" file will have a script to delete data in a XML file, just in case it changes something. (for now Im trying with a simple php line)

---

EDIT

The real PHP code that will go in the PHP file is this :

```
<?php
$xml = simplexml_load_file("signatures.xml");
$name = $_POST['nom'];
$signs = $xml->xpath('//Signature[Nom = "'.$name.'"]');
$xml -> SignaturesParent -> removeChild($signs);
?>
```

Nothing happens when I try that.

Comment: Ajax will receive the 301 Status from your PHP. What do you want it to do with that?

Comment: I'm trying to delete data from a XML file using the code I added in my post Edit. Thanks!

Comment: Re: Edit, maybe you should write the changed xml back to a file??? See http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.asxml.php Redical I know!

Comment: Why not add `echo "Child Deleted";` from your PHP at the end. Then in your ajax call, you can look for that. `success: function(data){ if(data == "Child Deleted"){ alert('Worked'); } else { alert("Failed"); };` Plus what @RiggsFolly said too.

Comment: Also where is `$_POST['nom'];` coming from?

Comment: The $_POST['nom'] comes from a text field in my html file. What I need is that is the name in the text field (nom) equals to "John" for example, and that I click on the Delete button, it scans the XML file to check if there's a Signature name="John" node in my XML file, and if so, delete it.

Comment: self-duplicate / x/y / pressure-repost of: [Deleting a specific node based on dropdown selection in XML](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31945165/367456)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

> The ajax call now alerts whatever is sent to it from the `delete.php`
>
> The ajax call does a POST and not a GET so that it matches the fact that you are using $_POST[''] and send some data i.e. `smith` **you are going to have to change that to something that actually exists in your XML file**
>
> The `delete.php` actually returns something
>
> The `delete.php` saves the changed xml document back to disk to a file with a different name, so you can see if it actually did anything. *just while you are tesing.*

```
<script>
  $(function () {

    $('#deleteform').on('submit', function (e) {

      e.preventDefault();
      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'delete.php',
        data: {nom:"smith"},
        success: function (data) {
          alert(data);
        }
      });
    });
  });
</script>



<?php
$xml = simplexml_load_file("signatures.xml");
$name = $_POST['nom'];
$signs = $xml->xpath('//Signature[Nom = "'.$name.'"]');
$xml -> SignaturesParent -> removeChild($signs);

$result = $xml->asXML("signatures2.xml");
echo $result ? 'File Saved' : 'File Not Saved';

?>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. But it gives me that error in a alert box: <br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Call to undefined method SimpleXMLElement::removeChild() in <b>/PATH TO FILE/delete.php</b> on line <b>6</b><br />

Comment: That was code I assumed you had already checked, but apparently not, so read this to see how to remove an element http://stackoverflow.com/questions/262351/remove-a-child-with-a-specific-attribute-in-simplexml-for-php/16062633#16062633

Comment: Thanks! I'll take a look again at that link to find out whats wrong with my code.